# Is it bad to wash yourself with cold water

Tags: muscle

I am a runner and sometimes get sore muscles. I was told by one of my friends that I should wash my legs with cold water. But I have been told by someone else that this can cause arthritis.

Is this true?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cold water definitely doesn't cause arthritis but it certainly helps to release muscle stress. Infact hot and cold therapy is suggested to patients with arthritis. When you run you cause wear and tear in your muscles and also sweat causing your body temperature to rise. Cold water brings your heated muscles back to homeostasis faster than your body will. Arthritis is caused by inflammation of joints which is caused by excessive wear and tear and unless you allow your body(immune system) to heal those microtrauma in your leg muscles caused by running you might eventually cause inflammation which is what arthritis is. A healthy immune system is protective. It generates internal inflammation to get rid of infection and prevent disease. But the immune system can mistakenly attack the joints with uncontrolled inflammation, potentially causing joint erosion.

Here is a link for more information: http://www.arthritis.org/about-arthritis/understanding-arthritis/what-is-arthritis.php

Comment: You make several assertions of fact in this answer. Those assertions need to be supported with reliable sources.

Comment: I'll update my answer with links. Thanks for the suggestion.